# Add Current Date/Time to downloaded file in PHP

Tags: php, filenames

I have a link that downloads a current database Table, I need to it to have the current date attached at the end of the filename every time?

```
   header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=CARD_MASTER**DATE HERE**.xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    print "$header\n$data";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=CARD_MASTER-".date('Y-m-d').".xls");
```

I just used the Y-m-d format, you can use a different variation by looking into the `date()` function

Comment: @WHITEBOX, if this answer helped solve your problem, please mark it as accepted - it's the stack overflow way of saying *Thank you!*

Comment: @miku: with that avatar he isn't gonna pick any answer i believe :)

Answer (score 2):

You can insert a date in the header, as you would in any string:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=CARD_MASTER-" . 
    date("m-d-y") . ".xls");
```